# maven scm url generate

Tags: maven, maven-scm

Currently doing some refactoring. Consolidating modules and creating new ones. Is there a way for Maven to generate the scm urls for each maven module rather than me going thru each module manually?

Comment: specifying the url alone should be enough. Maven actually can figure out where to do the tagging.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if any existing plugin does this.

Even if Maven were to figure out which SCM is being used for the module, it would be quite a job to determine which branch/tag/trunk of that SCM the source code is.